# Misterious GroupHomepage Feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, features

In SharePoint Online, as part of the Modern Team site, there is a  **GroupHomepage** **Web** feature with the ID e3dc7334-cec0-4d2c-8b90-e4857698fc4e. This feature does not exist even in SharePoint 2019.

Does anyone know what this feature is supposed to do? I could not find any documentation describing it. I have checked if this feature exusted as part of a classic Team site and it it's not present there. So I am curious what this does exactly.

This is how I have retrieved this feature:

```
Get-PnPFeature -Scope Web
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a feature that has not been released to the public yet and is only available in SharePoint online.

Comment: Well, that's the strange thing. this feature is already there and it's already activated. I could be wrong, but it was already there since at least 2018. It's just weird it's not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GroupHomepage** (e3dc7334-cec0-4d2c-8b90-e4857698fc4) is a hidden feature that is activated by defaul on the modern team sites. Does not matter if the site is Office 365 Group-connected or not.

The name of this feature might be misleading. The feature does not really do anything related to the unified Office 365 groups.

When this feature is **activated**:

- Home.aspx file is added to the SitePages library. Only if **Home.aspx** did not exist.
- The page is given 0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118 content type. Which is a Modern Page.
- **PageLayoutType** property of this page is set to **Home**. This layout is unique because it has no large top header that takes up a lot of space. Also, this layout does not allow comments (AAIK).
- The Home.aspx page is published.
- Home.aspx page is set as a site's home page.

When you deactivate the feature literary nothing will happen. The feature has no **FeatureDeactivated** receiver.

The code for the feature is located in the **Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal** dll (SP 2019), in the **GroupHomepageFeatureReceiver** class.

[image]

**Experiment**

On a classic team site, I have renamed a default Home.aspx page to Home2.aspx and then activated the feature:

```
# Enable Modern home page (GroupHomepage) feature:
Enable-PnPFeature  e3dc7334-cec0-4d2c-8b90-e4857698fc4e
```

This is the result:
[image]

**Conclusion**

This is a very simple feature. It just creates a new modern home page if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Group Homepage feature creates a home page based on defined in the feature home.aspx file.

Reference:

http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/en/sharepoint-new-team-site-inside-out

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the feature that adds the home page / group features for Office 365 Group connected Team Sites. This is also why you won't find it on classic team sites or on on-premise SharePoint environments.

The home page is quite different from the home page you get for the non-group connected sites. For example:

- Navigation includes "Convesations" and suggests group resources to add to navigation (Planner, OneNote, Calendar)
- Includes activity from other group connected apps, not just the SharePoint site itself
- Shows members of the Office 365 Group
- Has a callout when hovering the site name
- Link for Teamifying the Office 365 Group

Comment: I was thinking along the same line. But what makes me confused is that this feature is already activated on Modern Team sites that are not connected to Office 365 groups. So I wonder if this feature does anything for standalone Team sites?

Comment: Probably not. Today the home pages look quite identical - this was not the case before the "Non group connected Team Sites" was introduced a while back. I'm guessing the feature was just carried over and does basically nothing for these sites :)